# tikz + tikzposter: Getting layers right

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzposter

Why are not all lines over the bubbles? I am talking especially about the line that goes from "normal" to "adsf".

*Disclaimer: What I actually want to do in my work is, to have the lines underneath but they aren't (layers are reversed in order of course). However, I am not able to reproduce a MWE somehow, so I figured if the issue can be solved the way shown here, I should be able to get it right in my actual work.*

```
\documentclass[a2paper]{tikzposter}  % See Section 3
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains,positioning,calc,trees,mindmap,backgrounds}

\pgfdeclarelayer{mindmaplayer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{linelayer}
\pgfsetlayers{backgroundlayer,main,notelayer,mindmaplayer,linelayer}

\title{Title}   \institute{Inst} % See Section 4.1
\author{Auth}   \titlegraphic{Logo}
\usetheme{Basic}  % See Section 5


\tikzset{
        isNode/.style args = {color#1connected to#2}{concept, concept color=#1, alias=this,
            append after command = {\pgfextra{ \begin{pgfonlayer}{linelayer} \draw[dashed,ultra thick,red] (this)--(#2); \end{pgfonlayer} }}
        },
        toNode/.style = {concept, concept color=#1},
        %
        isConc/.style = {concept, concept color=orange},
        toConc/.style = {concept, concept color=orange},
        is6/.style = {isNode = color blue connected to othernode},
        to6/.style = {toNode = blue}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\block{BlocktitleA}{

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{mindmaplayer}
\node[fill=red, circle] (othernode) at (7,7) {adsf};
\path[mindmap, isConc] (0,0cm) node[isConc] {Statistic} [clockwise from=90]
    child[toConc] { node[isConc] {general theory}
        child[to6] { node[is6] {intro} }
        child[to6] { node[is6] {outro} }
    }
    child[toConc] { node[isConc] {distributions} [clockwise from=-30]
        child[to6] { node[is6] {normal} }
        child[to6, sibling angle=-60] { node[is6] {binomial} }
    }  
;
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `(this.center)--(#2.center);` I get ("adsf" now in green)

[image]

#### File list

```
 *File List*
tikzposter.cls    2014/01/15 v2.0 LaTeX document class for Posters
 xkeyval.sty    2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
      ae.sty    2001/02/12 1.3 Almost European Computer Modern
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
   t1aer.fd    1997/11/16 Font definitions for T1/aer.
 xstring.sty    2013/10/13  v1.7c  String manipulations (C Tellechea)
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
extarticle.cls    1996/10/08 v1.0 Non Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 exscale.sty    2007/10/29 v2.1h Standard LaTeX package exscale
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
  a0size.sty    2004/01/31 v1.22b a0poster class (GK, MW)
tikzposterColorpalettes.tex
tikzposterColorstyles.tex
tikzposterBackgroundstyles.tex
tikzposterTitlestyles.tex
tikzposterBlockstyles.tex
tikzposterInnerblockstyles.tex
tikzposterNotestyles.tex
tikzposterLayoutthemes.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

Comment: You can reproduce this issue without the poster code and with many fewer libraries. I guess this is probably to do with the way the mind map is drawn, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @cfr: No I cannot. The issue seems to arrive precisely because of the combination with tikzpicture: Not using tikzpicture does not yield this error.

Comment: OK. ***I*** can reproduce this issue....

Comment: @cfr: So what is the reason for this issue? Simply my old version of tikz?

Comment: No. The reason is the one identified in [Ignasi's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281339/). However, it may well be, as emerges in the comments that you *also* need to update in order for things to work properly. It is hard to say whether this is why Ignasi's code doesn't work for you since you didn't really say how it didn't work, but only that it didn't. But it is very likely that you will not get the same results in many cases with TikZ 2.1 as you would with the newer version since quite a lot has changed and there are new features (and new bugs).

Comment: @cfr: What I meant was that using Ignasi's answer does not change anything for me: It just looks like me picture.

Comment: Then probably, yes, you need to update TeX.

Answer (score 2):

All of them are over the bubbles because you draw them on most upper layer `linelayer`. But as you draw them with `\draw[dashed,ultra thick,red] (this)--(#2);` all lines stop at bubbles borders, as usual with nodes connections. If you want to draw these lines between bubbles centers and test that all lines are over bubbles use `\draw[dashed,ultra thick,red] (this.center)--(#2.center);` or 
`\draw[dashed,ultra thick,red] (this.center)--(#2);` which was used to obtain:

[image]

Complete code and version list:

```
\documentclass[a2paper]{tikzposter}  % See Section 3
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains,positioning,calc,trees,mindmap,backgrounds}

\pgfdeclarelayer{mindmaplayer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{linelayer}
\pgfsetlayers{backgroundlayer,main,notelayer,mindmaplayer,linelayer}

\title{Title}   \institute{Inst} % See Section 4.1
\author{Auth}   \titlegraphic{Logo}
\usetheme{Basic}  % See Section 5


\tikzset{
        isNode/.style args = {color#1connected to#2}{concept, concept color=#1, alias=this,
            append after command = {\pgfextra{ \begin{pgfonlayer}{linelayer} \draw[dashed,ultra thick,red] (this.center)--(#2); \end{pgfonlayer} }}
        },
        toNode/.style = {concept, concept color=#1},
        %
        isConc/.style = {concept, concept color=orange},
        toConc/.style = {concept, concept color=orange},
        is6/.style = {isNode = color blue connected to othernode},
        to6/.style = {toNode = blue}
}

\listfiles
\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\block{BlocktitleA}{

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{mindmaplayer}
\node[fill=red, circle] (othernode) at (7,7) {adsf};
\path[mindmap, isConc] (0,0cm) node[isConc] {Statistic} [clockwise from=90]
    child[toConc] { node[isConc] {general theory}
        child[to6] { node[is6] {intro} }
        child[to6] { node[is6] {outro} }
    }
    child[toConc] { node[isConc] {distributions} [clockwise from=-30]
        child[to6] { node[is6] {normal} }
        child[to6, sibling angle=-60] { node[is6] {binomial} }
    }  
;
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
 *File List*
tikzposter.cls    2014/01/15 v2.0 LaTeX document class for Posters
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
      ae.sty    2001/02/12 1.3 Almost European Computer Modern
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
   t1aer.fd    1997/11/16 Font definitions for T1/aer.
 xstring.sty    2013/10/13  v1.7c  String manipulations (C Tellechea)
etoolbox.sty    2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
extarticle.cls    1996/10/08 v1.0 Non Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 exscale.sty    2014/09/29 v2.1h Standard LaTeX package exscale
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
  a0size.sty    2004/01/31 v1.22b a0poster class (GK, MW)
tikzposterColorpalettes.tex
tikzposterColorstyles.tex
tikzposterBackgroundstyles.tex
tikzposterTitlestyles.tex
tikzposterBlockstyles.tex
tikzposterInnerblockstyles.tex
tikzposterNotestyles.tex
tikzposterLayoutthemes.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********
```

Comment: I updated my question. For the presented scenario I want them on top, but they aren't. With your code it does not work for me either.

Comment: @user49283 I've included my complete code and result and also which package versions am I using. Please test yours.

Comment: I used your code: My result stays as it was. I included the file list - are you able to detect the culprit?

Comment: @user49283 As you can see comparing both lists, you are still using TiKZ 2.1. In fact looks like all you TeX system is old. Which system do you use?You should try to update it.

Comment: I am on Kubuntu 14.4, so some packages are a little behind. How do I upgrade LaTeX outside of the package manager's bounderies?

Comment: @user49283 http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu?s=7|1.2318.