# Tikz: Redrawing a node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have node (say `\node (mynode) at (0,10) {\blindtext};`). How can I redraw it with something like `\draw[redraw=mynode]`?

Comment: If you tell us what you are tying to achieve maybe we can give you advice on how to do it without requiring redrawing the node. For example, if your problem is that you want to use the node's name as a coordinate but want to draw it above something that comes after in the code, you may use layers which require no redrawing.

Comment: @Bordaigorl: Layers don't work for my case, because I am using `tikzposter` and I can't use the most current version of tikz - I tried in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281238/49283. I want to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/282163/49283. Using tcolorbox does not solve my problem in the end, because it does not solve http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282244/49283.

Comment: Adding the version constraint in the question might be a good idea. Also, a MWE is necessary to address your question properly.

Comment: @Bordaigorl: Find all the information attached.

Comment: If you really want to redraw the node why not defining a macro like `\newcommand{\mynode}[1][]{\node (mynode#1) at (0,10) {\blindtext};}` and use it twice?

Comment: @Bordaigorl: I tried something similar in my second try in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/282163/49283 (including a MWE) - can you tell, why this did not work?

Comment: I am sorry but I find it very unclear what you are asking in all the questions you are mentioning...you should make the effort of isolating the problem you are trying to solve in a MWE with clear requirements (e.g. version of TikZ)

Answer (score 2):

With TikZ v3 you can shift the node specifications to a style. I don't know your intention but here is an example

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[mynode/.style={at={(1,0)},node contents={asdfasdf}}]
\node[mynode];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I don't have TikZ v3, but only v2 and installing another version seems surprising difficult/risky on Linux.

Comment: Also, this is not what I was looking for. I want to specify a node not in a style but just as normally done in the tikzpicture. Then later I just want to redraw it. This is useful if the node has been drawn over and as you know by now, I have trouble using the layers correctly. But even even if the layers worked this would be useful in cases where there is just a couple of nodes I want to redraw which might be enough to justify a layer if you will.